# Spring cache and detached entity passed to persist

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot 3.2.2 with spring data jpa

I have an entity User

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
    private City city;

}
```

I try to do an update

```
public UserPayload updateUser(UserPayload userPayload){


    User user = userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("User " + id))

    if (userPayload.cityId() != null) {
        City city = cityService.getCity(userPayload.getCityId());
        user.setCity(city);

    }else{
        user.setCity(null);
    }     

}



@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class CityCacheService {

    private final CityRepository cityRepository;

    @Cacheable("City")
    @Transactional
    public List<City> cityRepository() {
        return cityRepository.findAll();
    }

}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class CityService {

    private final CityCacheService cityCacheService;

    @Transactional
    public City getCity(Long id) {
         Optional<City> cityOpt = cityCacheService.findAll().stream().filter(c -> c.getId().equals(id)).findFirst();
    return cityOpt.orElse(null);;
    }

}
```

When city change, i get an error

detached entity passed to persist